# JavaScript and bitwise operators

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

Why is in JavaScript:

`console.log('1000' | '1010'); // 1018` not '1010'?

and

`console.log('1000' & '1010'); // 992` not '1000'?

What ist the right way for bitwise calculation in JavaScript?

Comment: Note that bitwise operations in JavaScript are unusually slow, JS uses doubles for its number type but 32bit integers for bitwise meaning it has to convert, do the bitwise operation, and convert back *every time*.

Comment: @ kjaquier: No! - same result with numbers!

Answer (score 4):

You have to define the input as binary number :

```
console.log(0b1000 | 0b1010); 
> 10
```

Then you can convert back the decimal number to binary notation:

```
Number(10).toString(2);
> "1010"
```

Comment: Thanks, works with binary numbers and "binary strings" also!

Answer (score 4):

it's using the binary equivalent of the decimal numbers you put in. You are actually getting

```
0000001111101000 | 0000001111110010
0000001111101000 & 0000001111110010
```

which are equivalent to 1018 and 992 in decimal

Comment: Thanks, I understand now the problem and result.

Answer (score 3):

input numbers need to be defined in binary. after operation you need to convert the result to binary again since bitwise operation produces decimal number. following code will produce your desired output.

```
console.log(('0b1000' | '0b1010').toString(2));
console.log(('0b1000' & '0b1010').toString(2));
```